# Book ID: Dragon Madness

Tags: story-identification, books

There's one book that I can't remember that's been bugging me recently.

I don't remember much of the book other than a plot point was that there was this ritual that a character either heard of or had to go through, and one of the caveats of this ritual is that if you failed it or if something went wrong you lived but got hit with something called "Dragon Madness". The people who had been afflicted with it ended up hiding in caves, and clawing at their skin and eyes.

Unfortunately I remember nothing else about the book aside from that. I'm curious if anyone recognizes it from anywhere in particular.

Comment: It's not "How to Train your Dragon" by any chance?

Comment: One possibility is the Dark Sun book, "The Rise and Fall of the Dragon King". There is a ritual which allows one to transform into a dragon, and the term "dragon madness" is used, but I can't find much more about that.